# Why isn't VMware Client Integration plugin running on Mac OS X 10.11?

Tags: mac-osx, vmware-vcenter

I've downloaded and seem to have successfully installed, however when I try to use it, vCenter acts like the plugin is not installed.

The log file, in `~/VMware/CIP/ui/sessions/session_0000/logs/csd.log`, includes messages like:

```
[2015-12-16 12:51:12] at [bora/vim/apps/csd/web/WebSocketServer.cpp:225] [ERRO] Web Socket Server [50100] Terminated With Exception: resolve: Host not found (authoritative)
```

Running the "vmware-csd-installer" gives some hints of a problem:

```
$ /Applications/VMware\ Client\ Integration\ Plugin.app/Contents/Library/vmware-csd-installer 
dyld: Library not loaded: /build/toolchain/mac32/openssl-1.0.1m/lib/libcrypto.1.0.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/VMware Client Integration Plugin.app/Contents/Library/lib/libssl.1.0.1.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: What version of VMware vCenter?

Answer (score 1):

The apparent solution I found was to create a folder and some symlinks, and then run the main GUI installer for the plugin again:

```
$ sudo mkdir -pv /build/toolchain/mac32/openssl-1.0.1m/lib
$ cd /build/toolchain/mac32/openssl-1.0.1m/lib
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/VMware\ Client\ Integration\ Plugin.app/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.1.0.1.dylib
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/VMware\ Client\ Integration\ Plugin.app/Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.1.0.1.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the installer finishes, but silently fails due to missing libraries, libraries that probably existed in earlier OS X versions.

Because the libraries don’t exist, necessary certificates don’t get generated, and even re-running the installer from the application directory won’t solve it (including with the below hack). What you need to do is ensure the libraries will be there when the installer gets to the “Running package scripts…” section on initial install.

There are a number of possible solutions, including the one above, but the below seems the cleanest and doesn’t require multiple installs.

Before installing the application, do the following:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /build/toolchain/mac32/openssl-1.0.1m
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/VMware\ Client\ Integration\ Plug-in.app/Contents/Frameworks /build/toolchain/mac32/openssl-1.0.1m/lib
```

Then run the full installer.

This will create a hack to allow the packaged libraries to be used when the package scripts get run. If it’s working correctly the “Running package scripts…” will take many minutes to run as it executes “openssl” to generate the following:

```
/Applications/VMware Client Integration Plug-in.app/Contents/Library/data/ssl/dh512.pem
```

If it instead installs very quickly, you can be fairly certain it didn’t installed correctly and probably VMware has changed something yet again. If it works, you can both upload files and deploy OVF files.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work for 10.13.5